# How to convert mm:ss.ms to ss.ms?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime, milliseconds

I'm trying to make a conversion for below example:

`original time: 1:03.091`
`converted time: 63.09`

I did some research and found that I can add up the min to secs, but don't know how to add the milliseconds anymore. Below is what I've managed to do so far:

```
a = "01:40.44"
x = time.strptime(a,'%M:%S.%f')                                              
datetime.timedelta(minutes=x.tm_min,seconds=x.tm_sec).total_seconds()

100.0
```

In this case, how could I get `100.44`, for example?

Comment: [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... 
[Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: [`time.struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time) instances don't look like they have fractions of seconds. But `datetime.dateime` objects do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `datetime` instead of `time`. For example:

```
>>from datetime import datetime
>>x = datetime.strptime(a,'%M:%S.%f')
1900-01-01 00:01:40.437000
>>x.microsecond
437000
```

Edit: You can get anything hour, min, second and sum it up.

from datetime import datetime

```
a = "01:40.437"
x = datetime.strptime(a,'%M:%S.%f')
time = x.minute*60+x.second+x.microsecond/1000000

>>time
100.437
```

Comment: Hi @NLag, thanks but this is not what the intended output though..In this case, I'll need `100.44`, not getting microseconds..

Comment: I edited the answer you need, using the `datetime` you can extract other part just like with `time`